# Can't show inline image and html export

Tags: org-export, inline-image

I am losing my mind with this one, since I feel I am not completely new to emacs. Or so I thought.

I usually need to print a html report, together with having inline images activated. However, some configuration in my header seems to make both incompatible. I tried to remove configurations from the header as much as I could. In the simple example below the resulting image is not being shown in emacs, nor the image is being  loaded in the html when running org-html-export-html:

```
#+TITLE: Simulate ACE data (latent / obs phenotype)
#+DATA: 2023
#+STARTUP: latexpreview
#+PROPERTY: cache yes
#+PROPERTY: tangle yes
#+OPTIONS: broken-links:t
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 300px
#+PROPERTY: results graphics


#+BEGIN_SRC R :session r-session :dir "." :results output graphics file :file mtcars.png
plot(mtcars)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:mtcars.png]]
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

- What am I doing wrong
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH5Ni.png

Comment: For the export, you need a `:exports results` header in the code block. I'm not sure why you cannot display the image inline: `M-x org-display-inline-images` works for me.